# How to make a randomly generated Python Variable from a list and keep its value across functions

Tags: python, list, function, random

I have a function `test1()` and in this function, there is a variable `w` which is a randomly generated element from a list `l`. I want to use the value of `w` in another function `test2`, but keep the value it generated in `test1`. my current code is:

```
import random
def test1 ():
    l = [1,2,3]
    w = random.choice(l)
    print(w)


def test2 ():
    w = test1()
    print(w)


test1()
test2()
```

with the current code, I get two different values for the variable w, I want its value to be randomly generated once, then be able to use that value across different functions.

Comment: Please repeat your instructional materials on using functions.  Pay special attention to how you return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test1 doesn't return anything, you have to return w and if you want always the same value you can set a seed:

```
import random
random.seed(42)
def test1 ():
    l = [1,2,3]
    w = random.choice(l)
    print(w)
    return w


def test2 ():
    w = test1()
    print(w)


test1()
test2()
```

Comment: Thanks, do you mind explaining how seeds work?

Comment: Here is an explanation: https://pynative.com/python-random-seed/

Comment: one more question, this method generates the same number each time but say that I wanted a different number each time but I want it to stay the same when used in different functions. For example, w takes the value of 2, now when I use w its value is 2. If i run this again w could be 1 so when I use w in this instance it remains as 1. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: No, that can't be done because you are using the random package. If you want you have to generate a list with random values and pass to another value of the list each time but if you want that you have to ask another question

Comment: could you show me a simple example?